# jQuery Script creates infinite loop in Firefox (only)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a jQuery Script which checks the window size and increases the outer wrapper to fit perfectly into the users window.

```
function reSize($target){
    $target.css('width', $(window).width()+'px');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).bind('resize', reSize($('#blocker')));
        $(window).trigger('resize');

        while($(window).height() < $('.newcontainer').height()+30){
            $('.newcontainer').css('width', $('.newcontainer').width() - 10 +'px');
        }

        $('#chatfenster').css('height', $('.newcontainer').height() - 260 +'px');
        $('#userlist').css('height', $('.newcontainer').height() - 350 +'px');
    }, 100);
});
```

It works very smooth in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox it's freezing and I don't know why. Sometimes I feel like Firefox is the new IE.

http://design.maxxcoon.com/bestlife/webinar_chat/ (**don't open this link in firefox because it crashes the browser**)

Can anybody help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Sometimes I feel like Firefox is the new IE.` Sometimes users coding as non-standarized craps that works in a buggy chrome (-webkit- overprefixed code) but the standards said the opposite. Firefox works as the standards said.

Comment: And please, **attach a working example and not a web that you know that freezes the browser!!!!**. Read this carefully : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just a tip: every jquery select that you do should be stored in a variable and reused, well .. if you need to re-use it a couple of times. so do `var $window = $(window);` once and reuse `$windows`. Same thing for `.newcontainer`. Don't start a new jquery select for the same element.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude:
Everybody can make mistakes and no-one is perfect. As a front-end designer who is working most of the time with CSS I can tell you, that Firefox can be very buggy. I thought this might be something like that aswell. I was wrong but there is no need to talk to a human being like that, espacially not when this person asks politely for help. If you aren't patient enough to help other people who may not be as far as you in a certain subject, so please don't help at all! You did not help, you just showed "how bad I am, and how good you are". Please don't ever help me again.

Comment: Nobody is perfect, and I don't said to you that you are bad and I am good. However, the bug were in your code not in Firefox. As a webdeveloper with more than 15 years experience, I can tell you that standards are the good choice. Firefox works with standards. But you can think what you want. You'll be surprised how many questions here said "Firefox not working, chrome yes, firefox is new IE" and then the problem is that chrome is working wrong (even if a code works, it doesn't means that chrome is working fine). Don't worry, I don't help you if I see you. Good luck.

Comment: I edit because the link is still in the post. I don't remove it but I write an alert.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude:
After reading your links (the second time) I am not sure how my question should be asked the right way. You say I should attach a working example, well I thought that was what I did (this can be understood by reading my post carefully). Also I told in my post, that Firefox is freezing so this is what everybody can expect. How else can I show the wrong behaviour? And always keep in mind please, that one questionmark is enough. You don't see me screaming into your face do you?
I don't care if you are a good programmer, but you are not a good teacher.

Comment: As a front-enddeveloper with 15 years of experience I can show the standard CSS code which DON'T work well in Firefox. So saying that Firefox works as standard is an absolute definition of an infailurable behaviour which is not true! No browser works 100% they all have bugs, one more than the other. You should know that after 15 years.

Comment: I said that don't attach a link and attach a working example because you don't share a working example, you share a piece of code. Attach a link that you know that can freeze the users' browser is dangerous, you can put to trash the possible work that users have in another tabs without recovering option. Sorry if all of this disturbs you, but I think that's not a good practice

Comment: Thanks for not helping. I really appreciate that.

Comment: How should I attach a working example? That's a paradoxon!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers it is very clear about working examples. You can use stacksnippets or an external tool like jsfiddle.net . However, I'm a bad guy, maybe this is wrong. But it's the way that stackoverflow works.

Comment: I don't see how "jsfiddle.net" can help me here? When I put the code into jsfiddle it will also freeze with FF and if not, the problem isn't accessable. That don't make any sense for me. How should I show a freezing browser without showing a freezing browser? That doesn't work for me. But it's OK, I don't wanna argue with you.
Live long and proper.

Answer (score 2):

This part is very unreliable:

```
    while($(window).height() < $('.newcontainer').height()+30){
        $('.newcontainer').css('width', $('.newcontainer').width() - 10 +'px');
    }
```

You are checking the `height` of the window against the `height` of the first element found with a `class` of `newcontainer`. As long as the height of the window is smaller than that height plus 30 pixels, you set the `width` of all elements with `class="newcontainer"` to 10 less than the `width` of the first one of them.

If your condition is for one dimension (`height`) and the changes you make is to another dimension (`width`), the loop will run either never, or probably forever, or possibly randomly...

If there is a maximum height or a maximum width for your `.newcontainer` elements, you should instead calculate the allowed values for `height` or `width` and set them **once**, not in a loop! Something like this, maybe:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var maximumContainerHeight = windowHeight - 30;
$('.newcontainer').css('height', maximumContainerHeight + 'px');
```

However, I do not know if you want to set width or height, so I'm guessing.

If what you are doing is really setting the width of something, **hoping** that the layout engine will affect the height as a side-effect, you are going at this the very wrong way.

Another, better, solution is to use **modern CSS solutions**, like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), to let the browser automatically handle all layout issues.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
I want the whole frame (.newcontainer) to fit into the window of the browser so there shouldn't be any scroll-bars.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
I want the whole frame (newcontainer) to fit into the window of the browser so there shouldn't be any scroll-bars.
When I set the width, I can let CSS do the rest with the height, but that doesn't work the other way, so I need to set the width of the (newcontainer).
It's behaviour should be like in Chrome or Safari. So there is no need for changing the effect. I just want to do it right without any bugs.
First I check if newcontainer ist higher than the window.height (if yes, that means it's outside the window). If so, I want to increase the width as long as nessecary.

Comment: btw. flexbox isn't an option, because it doesn't support IE8 or IE9

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out without a loop.
May be helpful for others.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function reSize($target){
$target.css('width', $(window).width()+'px');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', reSize($('#blocker')));
    $(window).trigger('resize');

    var windowSize = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $('.newcontainer').height();
    var containerWidth = $('.newcontainer').width();

    if(containerHeight > windowSize){
        var pixelToMuch = containerHeight - windowSize;
        var divFactor = pixelToMuch * 1.67;
        var newWidth = containerWidth - divFactor;
        $('.newcontainer').css('width',newWidth+'px');
    }

    $('#chatfenster').css('height', $('.newcontainer').height() - 260 +'px');
    $('#userlist').css('height', $('.newcontainer').height() - 350 +'px');
}, 100);
});
</script>
```